# turbostat - Why sometimes RAMWatt is about 100 in idle?

Tags: linux, drivers, ram

By using turbostat command we can check the power consumption of RAM.

ex:

```
  CPU%c6  ...    PkgWatt RAMWatt
  96.56   ...    64.43   93.12
```

CPU @ c6 state more than 95%, I think the system is in idle.

However, the RAMWatt is still about 93W, it is quite a lot.

I expected it is about 10W.

What's the reason make RAMWatt high?

Answer (score 2):

Normal dynamic RAM won't be able to keep its contents without power, and in fact needs their contents periodically refreshed. This is handled by the memory controller, which might be integrated to the CPU. In larger servers there might be multiple separate memory controller chips, each handling one part of the total memory of the server.

Static RAM would not need refresh cycles and would be faster, but is generally more expensive and cannot be packed as tightly on the chip as  dynamic RAM, and so it is only used in CPU caches, where you don't need quite so much memory, but it should be absolutely as fast as possible.

(A single bit of dynamic RAM requires one transistor and one capacitor; a single bit of static RAM requires 4-6 transistors.)

Flash memory would keep its contents with no power at all. But while flash memory can be read pretty fast, write operations to flash are still orders of magnitude slower than writing into RAM, mostly because *erasing* flash memory is slow. So you cannot just replace all your RAM with flash memory.

For more detail, please read this: https://computer.howstuffworks.com/question452.htm

Comment: In most of the cases ( 95%), the RAMWatt is about 10 ~ 20.